# node.js randomBytes() issue - use crypto to encrypt and decrypt data

Tags: node.js, encryption

I'm learning how to use the crypto module of node.js to encrypt and decrypt data. I've readed [this article](https://melvingeorge.me/blog/encrypt-decrypt-message-nodejs) and [this other article](https://www.htmlhints.com/article/encrypting-decrypting-data-with-nodejs-built-in-library-called-crypto/71), they will explain how to do the same thing but in a different way. I've read in the first article that there is an issue with `randomBytes()` but it's dated 2017 and maybe it's foxed in node 15. Since I want to pass a custom user password for the encryption key, can I use the `sha256` to hash the password and pass it for encryption? Something like

```
import crypto from 'crypto'

ipcMain.on('encryptMessage', (event, data) => {
 let iv = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex'); //I'm not sure if the string conversion is needed?
 let key = crypto.createHash('sha256')
 .update(data.password)
 .digest(); // If I understand digest will provide an human readable hash?
//encryption code here
});
```

Will be this ok for the encryption process, the password will be ok if hashed to be lenght almost 32 char?

Comment: Better use a password derivation function like PBKDF2 **and not** a simple hashing function like SHA256

Comment: @MichaelFehr so the hash way to get a key that will be 32 char length isn't the best approach right? And what about the `randomBytes()` issue, is fixed or I need to slice like explained into the first article linked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below you find a simple program that does a complete encryption - decryption using AES in CBC mode with a 32 byte long key derived from a passphrase with PBKDF2.

As the program is used within a cross platform project the output looks strange and you can adjust it to your needs. It runs on Node 12 without any problems, see it running in an online compiler here: https://repl.it/@javacrypto/CpcNodeJsCryptoAesCbc256Pbkdf2StringEncryptionFull#index.js

The issue in the linked article was a Node 5->6 migration issue.

**Security warning: the program has no exception handling and should be used for educational purpose only.**

This is the output:

```
AES CBC 256 String encryption with PBKDF2 derived key
plaintext:  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog

* * * Encryption * * *
ciphertext (Base64): VUH/MSEjdMOeLySYoVbQaaA30EVioZ9CXUXUDX69LG0=:kkz49Z23b0Q+D9LX1FHzaA==:VDWsYRpRmC5i2OyiMlBQLIzw2cW2Kdp2kxZKNzh/5vNcbCdMdEGInDoT7VIUCzzj
output is (Base64) salt : (Base64) iv : (Base64) ciphertext

* * * Decryption * * *
ciphertext (Base64):  VUH/MSEjdMOeLySYoVbQaaA30EVioZ9CXUXUDX69LG0=:kkz49Z23b0Q+D9LX1FHzaA==:VDWsYRpRmC5i2OyiMlBQLIzw2cW2Kdp2kxZKNzh/5vNcbCdMdEGInDoT7VIUCzzj
input is (Base64) salt : (Base64) iv : (Base64) ciphertext
plaintext:  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

code:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

console.log('AES CBC 256 String encryption with PBKDF2 derived key');

var plaintext = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';
console.log('plaintext: ', plaintext);
var password = "secret password";

console.log('\n* * * Encryption * * *');

var ciphertextBase64 = aesCbcPbkdf2EncryptToBase64(password, plaintext);
console.log('ciphertext (Base64): ' + ciphertextBase64);
console.log('output is (Base64) salt : (Base64) iv : (Base64) ciphertext');

console.log('\n* * * Decryption * * *');
var ciphertextDecryptionBase64 = ciphertextBase64;
console.log('ciphertext (Base64): ', ciphertextDecryptionBase64);
console.log('input is (Base64) salt : (Base64) iv : (Base64) ciphertext');
var decryptedtext = aesCbcPbkdf2DecryptFromBase64(password, ciphertextBase64);
console.log('plaintext: ', decryptedtext);

function aesCbcPbkdf2EncryptToBase64(password, data) {
  var PBKDF2_ITERATIONS = 15000;
  var salt = generateSalt32Byte();
  var key = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, salt, PBKDF2_ITERATIONS, 32, 'sha256');
  var iv = generateRandomInitvector();
  const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, iv);
  let encryptedBase64 = '';
  cipher.setEncoding('base64');
  cipher.on('data', (chunk) => encryptedBase64 += chunk);
  cipher.on('end', () => {
  // do nothing console.log(encryptedBase64);
  // Prints: some clear text data
  });
  cipher.write(data);
  cipher.end();
  var saltBase64 = base64Encoding(salt);
  var ivBase64 = base64Encoding(iv);
  return saltBase64 + ':' + ivBase64 + ':' + encryptedBase64;
}

function aesCbcPbkdf2DecryptFromBase64(password, data) {
  var PBKDF2_ITERATIONS = 15000;
  var dataSplit = data.split(":");
  var salt = base64Decoding(dataSplit[0]);
  var key = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, salt, PBKDF2_ITERATIONS, 32, 'sha256');
  var iv = base64Decoding(dataSplit[1]);
  var ciphertext = dataSplit[2];
  const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, iv);
  let decrypted = '';
  decipher.on('readable', () => {
    while (null !== (chunk = decipher.read())) {
      decrypted += chunk.toString('utf8');
    }
  });
  decipher.on('end', () => {
  // do nothing console.log(decrypted);
  });
  decipher.write(ciphertext, 'base64');
  decipher.end();
  return decrypted;
}

function generateSalt32Byte() {
  return crypto.randomBytes(32);
}

function generateRandomInitvector() {
  return crypto.randomBytes(16);
}

function base64Encoding(input) {
  return input.toString('base64');
}

function base64Decoding(input) {
  return Buffer.from(input, 'base64')
}
```